# Unsupported URL Error

Tags: ios, nsurl

I have a table view that contains articles from an RSS feed. It works fine if I set the URL like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://kyfbnewsroom.com/category/public-affairs/notifications/feed/"];
```

However, I'm trying to use this class for multiple URLs so I'm trying to pass the URL string to the class but I'm getting an unsupported URL error when doing it that way.

In my main menu to select a feed:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            ActionAlertsViewController *actionAlerts = [[ActionAlertsViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
            WebViewController *wvc = [[WebViewController alloc]init];
            [actionAlerts setWebViewController:wvc];
            actionAlerts.urlString = @"http://kyfbnewsroom.com/category/public-affairs/notifications/feed/";
            navController = [[KFBNavControllerViewController alloc]initWithRootViewController:actionAlerts];
            [UIView transitionWithView:appDelegate.window
                              duration:0.5
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                            animations:^{
                                appDelegate.window.rootViewController = navController;
                            }
                            completion:nil];
        }
```

Then in the table view that displays the articles:

```
- (void)fetchEntries
{
    xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

    // NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://kyfbnewsroom.com/category/public-affairs/notifications/feed/"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString];

    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
}
```

Comment: Try to print the url in console and check what is the modification in the two urls

Comment: Can you post full code?Where you calling this method "fetchEntries"?

Comment: fetchEntries is called in initWithStyle:

Answer (score 0):

Just put a break point on the `-(void)fetchEntries` and try to log `self.urlString` and verify whether you are getting the right url. The issue may be because of the wrong url.

Comment: Thats the reason. Provide a proper url so that it will work fine.

Comment: You have mentioned that fetchEntries is called in initWithStyle so the issue could be that your self.urlString property won't be set before the init method. Try to call fetchEntries after setting the self.urlString.